# Class Users not found in Phalcon 2

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

So basically I just installed Phalcon 2.0 on my ubuntu machine, with apache2, mysql and all the stuff installed. I went straight into the documentation of Phalcon to get me started. After following the exact steps from their [tutorial](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html), I got this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Users' not found in /var/www/html/phalcon/tutorial/app/controllers/SignupController.php on line 14

I think it may be related to namespacing of classes and stuff like that, but I wasn't able to figure it out so far.

Comment: What URL you type?

Comment: You sure you added `'../app/models/'` to the `$loader->registerDirs()` array?

Comment: @Tpojka this is the url (http://localhost/phalcon/tutorial/signup/register), it works fine for other routes, like tutorial, or tutorial/signup, i configured .htaccess to work.

Comment: @Phil Yes, i followed the tutorial and checked my code again and again.

Comment: So... can u provide git to check?

Comment: @BorisDelev: there it is https://github.com/phalcon/tutorial

Comment: @RaduDascalu - i download and test that tutorial and works fine. Even sign up part... so i think is somethink that uve changed. Is there a way to test your code?

Comment: @BorisDelev: I did not change any piece of code, in the end I even copy & pasted some of it. Maybe it's a problem I have with my server configuration on my PC, idk. I'l try to check again my code, and when I find some free time, I will upload it on github and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't register your folders properly. I add a resume of my code to give you an idea.

File `index.php`

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Micro;
use Phalcon\Events\Manager as EventsManager;

define('APP_DIR', dirname(__DIR__) .'/');

try {
    $config = require APP_DIR .'config/config.php';
    require APP_DIR .'config/loader.php';
    ...
} catch (Exception $e) {}
```

File `config.php`

```
return new Phalcon\Config([

    'application' => [
        'environment' => 'development',
        'controllers' => APP_DIR .'controllers/',
        'library' => APP_DIR .'library/',
        'models' => APP_DIR .'models/',
        'plugins' => APP_DIR .'plugins/',
        'routes' => APP_DIR .'routes/',
        'logs' => APP_DIR .'logs/',
        'base_uri' => '/',
        'debug' => false
    ]
]);
```

File `loader.php`

```
<?php

$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader;

// Register directories
$loader->registerDirs([
    $config->application->controllers,
    $config->application->library,
    $config->application->models,
    $config->application->plugins,
])->register();

// Composer autoloader
require_once APP_DIR .'vendor/autoload.php';
```

This should resolve any class specified in config folders.